# Python: Making Different Parameters Global

Tags: python, parameters, global

I am having problems making some variables global in this code. I would like the outputted numbers to be 4, 8, 6, and 10. The output is always just 1, 2, 3, and 4 like the function does not process the numbers at all. I tried making each variable global before, after, and inside the function, but this did not work. If anyone has a solution to this, it would be greatly appreciated. My actual code for my project has several more pairs of variables, I just included these to simplify it.

```
Xone = 1
Yone = 2
Xtwo = 3
Ytwo = 4
def function(parameterOne, parameterTwo):
    parameterOne = parameterOne + 3
    parameterTwo = parameterTwo + 6
function(Xone, Yone)
function(Xtwo, Ytwo)
print str(Xone)
print str(Yone)
print str(Xtwo)
print str(Ytwo)
```

Comment: What? You don't do anything to any of those variables within the function.

Comment: Parameters can never be global.

Comment: Of course they can. It's just that the OP is using immutable types. `Xone = [1]` and change `function` to parameterOne[0] = parameterOne[0] + 3. Xone == [4] after f(Xone) is called.

Answer (score 0):

Assign values to variables on return from function:

```
def function(parameterOne, parameterTwo):
    parameterOne = parameterOne + 3
    parameterTwo = parameterTwo + 6
    return parameterOne, parameterTwo

Xone, Yone = function(Xone, Yone)
```

Comment: Thank you for this help. This answers my question. I was able to use this in my project and it works! I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the computed values:

```
def function(parameterOne, parameterTwo):
    return (parameterOne + 3, parameterTwo + 6)

Xone = 1
Yone = 2
Xtwo = 3
Ytwo = 4

Xone, Yone = function(Xone, Yone)
Xtwo, Ytwo = function(Xtwo, Ytwo)

print str(Xone)
print str(Yone)
print str(Xtwo)
print str(Ytwo)
```

This returns:

```
4
8
6
10
```

Comment: Thank you for this help. This answers my question. I was able to use this in my project and it works! I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want modification inside the function - you may use mutable types, like class A:

Live demo: https://repl.it/repls/ActiveSpottedArizonaalligatorlizard